# Laravel Backpack - Set extra attributes before page save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud, laravel-backpack

In my **PageTemplates.php** I have a field like this:

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'adres',
    'label' => 'Adres',
    'type' => 'address',
    'fake' => true,
]);
```

Now I would like to save also the **latitude** and **longitude** of the address they give in (if it can be found). I've copied the **PageCrudController** and changed the config in **config/backpack/pagemanager.php** to:

```
return [
    'admin_controller_class' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageCrudController',
    'page_model_class'       => 'App\Models\Page',
];
```

In my **store** function I have:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $address = $request->request->get('adres');
    $addressObj = app('geocoder')->geocode($address)->get()->first();

    if($addressObj)
    {

    }

    $this->addDefaultPageFields(\Request::input('template'));
    $this->useTemplate(\Request::input('template'));

    return parent::storeCrud();
}
```

But what do I place in the if statement? How can I add (= set) an extra field to the extras field in my database?

Comment: Try like this `if($addressObj)
    {
        $request->latitude = '23.5';
        $request->latitude = '40.5';
    }`

Comment: Did you try as above commented ?

Comment: @user2486, tried it, but doesn't work. There not saved. This also doesn't work with other fields.

Comment: Where is `storeCrud` this function written ? is it also in `$this->storeCrud` or only in `parent::storeCrud` ?

Comment: Only parent::storeCrud.

Comment: then you can try only `$this->storeCrud` no need to call as `parent::`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing the following:

Add latitude and longitude as hidden fields:

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'latitude',
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'fake' => true,
]);

$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'longitude',
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'fake' => true,
]);
```

Set attributes by doing the following:

```
if($addressObj)
    {
        $request['latitude'] = $addressObj->getCoordinates()->getLatitude();
        $request['longitude'] = $addressObj->getCoordinates()->getLongitude();
    }
}
```

Change `parent::updateCrud` to `parent::updateCrud($request);`.

Answer (score 2):

In backpack 4.1, I solved my issue by the following way :
Override the store method in my controller, set my extra field in request and then call the backpack store method
Don't forget to add include backpack trait
Hope the solution will help someone

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }

public function store()
{
    $this->crud->setOperationSetting('saveAllInputsExcept', ['save_action']);
    $this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['updated_by' => backpack_user()->id]);     
        
    return $this->traitStore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking at this issue, I'd recommend you follow the advice in the note under the [Callbacks](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/getting-started-crud-operations#callbacks-1) section of Laravel Backpack's docs if you don't just want to observe changes made from the Backpack admin panel, you just need to create an Observable.

To do this you can do the following:

1. Create an Observer class: `php artisan make:observer YourObserver --model=YourModel`
2. Add your code to the generated event methods you wish to observe.
3. Register the Observer by calling the observe method on the model you wish to observe in your EventServiceProvider's boot method like so:

   ```php
   public function boot()
   {
       YourModel::observe(YourObserver::class);
   }
   ```

Or equally you can register the Observer to the `$observers` property of your applications' EventServiceProvider class:

```php
protected $observers = [
    YourModel::class => [YourObserver::class],
];
```